# $f\in L^1 [0,1]$, condition for integrability of $g =\int_x^1t^{-1} f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In my continuing studies towards an upcoming exam, I have run across a number of problems similar to the following, and would appreciate 1) some guidance on how to approach such problems in general and 2) how to solve this one in particular.

Let $f \in L^1[0,1]$ and define $g(x) = \int_{[x,1]} \frac{f(t)}{t} dt$. Show that $g \in L^1[0,1]$ and $\int_{[0,1]} g = \int_{[0,1]} f$.

I suspect the use of Tonelli's theorem is required, so I wrote

\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]} |g| &= \int_{[0,1]} \left| \int_{[x,1]} \frac{f(t)}{t} dt \right| dx \\
&= \int_{[0,1]} \left| \int_{[0,1]} \chi_{[x,1]} \frac{f(t)}{t} dt \right| dx \\
&= \int_{[0,1]} \left| \frac{f(t)}{t} \int_{[0,1]} \chi_{[x,1]} dx \right| dt 
\end{align*}

However, I'm not sure if this is even a productive direction. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it should hold for all $f \in L^1([0,\,1])$, it would in particular hold for positive $f$, so you must be able to move the absolute value into the inner integral. That yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]} \lvert g(x)\rvert\,dx &= \int_{[0,1]}\left\lvert \int_{[x,1]} \frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt\right\rvert\, dx\\
&\leqslant \int_0^1 \int_x^1 \frac{\lvert f(t)\rvert}{t}\,dt\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^t \frac{\lvert f(t)\rvert}{t}\,dx\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^t dx\right)\frac{\lvert f(t)\rvert}{t}\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \lvert f(t)\rvert\, dt.
\end{align}$$

Changing the order of integration is no problem because the integrand is measurable and non-negative.

The same computation without the absolute value yields (we now know that Fubini's theorem can be applied)

$$\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 f(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you be more explicit about how you changed the limits of integration? Also, the first part demonstrates that $g$ is integrable, so the latter computation is justified by Fubini, correct?

Comment: Edited to make it more explicit, hope that clarifies it. Yes, after the first part, we know Fubini is applicable.

Comment: @daniel -- I don't quite understand your explanation for being able to switch the integrals.  We know that f is L1 integrable, but we specifically don't know that f(t)/t is - it's part of what we are trying to prove.  I thought we could not switch order of integration unless both integrals converge.

Comment: @BettyMock $\frac{f(t)}{t}$ is in general not integrable. But the function $$h(x,t) = H(t-x)\cdot \frac{\lvert f(t)\rvert}{t},$$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function, is non-negative and measurable. By Tonelli's theorem, both iterated integrals and the two-dimensional integral are equal. Since one of them is finite, all of them are, and $h$ is integrable. From that we deduce that $H(t-x)\frac{f(t)}{t}$ is integrable too, hence 1) we can apply Fubini, and 2) $g$ is integrable.

Comment: @DanielFischer commented below my non-proof that I'm thinking the result isn't even true. Since f(x) = 1 is integrable, that would make f(x) = 1/x integrable.  Cannot see why it would be.  Maybe I'm confused about something, but would you be good enough to comment further?  Thanks.

Comment: @BettyMock For $f(t) = 1$, we get $g(x) = \int_x^1 \frac{dt}{t} = \log 1 - \log x = \log (1/x)$. While $1/x$ indeed is not integrable, $\log (1/x)$ is integrable. For $f \in L^1([0,1])$, the function $t \mapsto \frac{f(t)}{t}$ is in general not in $L^1([0,1])$, but it(s restriction) is in $L^1([x,1])$ for every $0 < x < 1$. That makes $g(x) = \int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt$ well-defined on $(0,1]$. And that function $g$ is again in $L^1([0,1])$.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I looked at it again, after seeing your note above, and I had really not read it right. I appreciate that you rewrote things in a way that was clearer to me. the result does make perfect sense once I put back the integral sign I lost. I've deleted my bad answer.