# Integrability of $g(x):= \int_x^1 t^{-1}f(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f \in L^1([0,1])$. Define for $x \in [0,1]$: $g(x):= \int_x^1 t^{-1}f(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(t)$.

I want to show that $g \in L^1([0,1])$ and $\int_0^1 g(x) d\mathcal{L}^1(x)=\int_0^1 f(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(t)$.

Assuming that $g$ is integrable, one can apply Fubini to get:

$\int_0^1 g(x) d\mathcal{L}^1(x)
= \int_0^1 \Big{(} \int_x^1 t^{-1}f(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(t) \Big{)} d\mathcal{L}^1(x) \\
=\int_0^1 \Big{(}\int_0^1 \chi_{[x,1]}(t) t^{-1}f(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(t) \Big{)} d\mathcal{L}^1(x) \\
=\int_0^1 \Big{(} \int_0^1 \chi_{[x,1]}(t) t^{-1}f(t)  d\mathcal{L}^1(x)\Big{)} d\mathcal{L}^1(t) \\
=\int_0^1 \Big{(} \int_0^1 \chi_{[x,1]}(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(x) \Big{)} t^{-1}f(t)  d\mathcal{L}^1(t)\\
=\int_0^1 f(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(t)$

since $\int_0^1 \chi_{[x,1]}(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(x)=t$.

So my question is how do I show that $\int_0^1 \Big{|} \int_x^1 t^{-1}f(t) d\mathcal{L}^1(t) \Big{|}d\mathcal{L}^1(x) < \infty$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f\in L^1 [0,1]$, condition for integrability of $g =\int_x^1t^{-1} f(t)dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480787/f-in-l1-0-1-condition-for-integrability-of-g-int-x1t-1-ftdt)